# How can I instantiate a Scala case object in Python using Py4J?

Tags: py4j

I have a Scala case object defined like so:

```scala
object DurationUnitsOfMeasure {
  sealed abstract class DurationUnitOfMeasure(val name : String)
  {
    override def toString : String = name
    lazy val initial: Char = name.charAt(2).toLower
  }
  case object Day extends DurationUnitOfMeasure("__DAY__")
  case object Week extends DurationUnitOfMeasure("__WEEK__")
  case object Month extends DurationUnitOfMeasure("__MONTH__")

  val durationUnitsOfMeasure : Seq[DurationUnitOfMeasure] = Seq(Day, Week, Month)
}
```

This gets used by some code I'm writing to interact with Spark. I also want to interact with that code from Python which I've done successfully using Py4J however I'm now at the point where I want to instantiate instances of that case object from Python/PySpark and I can't figure out how to do it.

I found a useful reference at https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/issues/109#issuecomment-504220206 that taught me to use `javap` to find the class structure of DurationUnitsOfMeasure

```sh
$ javap -classpath ../target/scala-2.11/foo_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com/package/DurationUnitsOfMeasure
Compiled from "File.scala"
public final class com.package.DurationUnitsOfMeasure {
  public static scala.collection.Seq<com.package.DurationUnitsOfMeasure$DurationUnitOfMeasure> durationUnitsOfMeasure();
}
```

which in turn led me to writing this python code:

```py
# self.spark is an instance of SparkSession
jDurationsUnitsOfMeasure = getattr(
            self.spark._sc._jvm.com.package.DurationUnitsOfMeasure,
            "durationUnitsOfMeasure")
```

`jDurationsUnitsOfMeasure` is a `<py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7fc0dbb14850` which I can interrogate using the usual python methods such as `dir()`:

> (Pdb) dir(jDurationsUnitsOfMeasure)
>   ['**call**', '**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**', '**le**', '**lt**', '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_build_args', '_gateway_doc', '_get_args', 'command_header', 'container', 'converters', 'gateway_client', 'name', 'pool', 'stream', 'target_id']

but I can't figure out how to do the thing I want to do which is to instantiate an instance of `DurationUnitsOfMeasure.Day`. I tried this:

```py
jDurationsUnitsOfMeasureDay = getattr(
            self.spark._sc._jvm.com.package.DurationUnitsOfMeasure,
            "durationUnitsOfMeasure$Day")
```

but that just bombed out with error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JError: com.package.DurationUnitsOfMeasure.durationUnitsOfMeasure$Day does not exist in the JVM

I feel like I'm not far away from being able to instantiate `DurationUnitsOfMeasure.Day` from Python, but I haven't solved it yet. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was over-complicating it. This works:

```py
jDurationUnitsOfMeasure = self.spark._sc._jvm.scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(
 self.spark._sc._jvm.com.package.DurationUnitsOfMeasure.durationUnitsOfMeasure())
```

That returns a `py4j.java_collections.JavaList` which exists so that this can be treated as a good ol' Python list therefore I can manipulate it as I would any other Python list (I prefer list comprehensions).